# Where can I find standard high school textbooks used in the US and UK?

Tags: united-states, teaching, united-kingdom, books

So for example, India has this government organization called The National Council of Educational Research and Training (NCERT). They produce their textbooks which are also available to download for free [here](http://ncert.nic.in/textbook/textbook.htm), for the grades 1-12 for all subjects. From my experience they are one of the highest quality textbooks in India.

Similarly, where can I access such textbooks which are of the highest quality, and are used in the US and/or UK? I'm mostly interested in searching for textbooks for the grades 8-12. I want to get a flavor of what kind of education do students get exposed to in the US/UK and I plan on reading their textbooks for the grades 8-12.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, at least, some of the states have lists of approved books. Texas for example has a list: https://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/handle/2152/19095

Maryland, or at least some large counties there, may also have such an approval process.

There are probably others. But note that some of the textbook selections in Texas are very controversial, as the selection board is sometimes dominated by creationists and other science deniers. So, use caution with this list and any other.

Comment: "as the selection board is sometimes dominated by creationists and other science deniers": I've stumbled on this when I was a high-school student, around 35 years ago, while reading a book from Asimov, which was a collection of essays on various topics. A chapter was dedicated to the increasing influence that creationists were having on educational choices in many US states. I couldn't believe that something like that was really happening (he's exaggerating!—I thought at the time), and I'm sad to apprehend that it does have happened.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, decisions of the Texas board are periodically in the US national news. I think the board members are elected officials and a lot of effort is put in to promoting these people and ideas. Climate change denial is another hot topic. We have a long way to go, I guess. The other problem with the Texas board is that since they control such a large market, publishers are too willing to cater to their demands. This is more serious, actually, than just what happens in Texas.